# Porgress bar is running faster on every onClick

Tags: android, dialog, progress-bar, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to make a simple audio recorder. The problem with the audio recorder is that,every time the progress bar gets faster. It would run fine on the first turn, but if you cancel the audio and want to go the second time, it gets faster.

```
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (recorder == null) {
                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    }
                    stopped=false;
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sample.3gp");
                    recorder.setMaxDuration(MAX_DURATION);

                    //Progressbar
                    pb.setMax(MAX_DURATION);
                    pb.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));

                    new CountDownTimer(MAX_DURATION, 250) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            pb.setProgress(pb.getProgress() + 250);
                        }
                        public void onFinish() {
                        }
                    }.start();
```

All of this is happening within a dialog, so how do I clear the dialog's contents so that the progress bar goes back to its default value.

Comment: Looks like you are adding 250 to the progress each time. You may need to store the progress when you cancel the audio and set it to where it left off when you start again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    long timestamp = DateUtils.getCurrentTimeMillis();
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testing/" + timestamp + "_D_FM_" + "John" + ".mp3";
    MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION); mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(imagePath);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
                mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                // Starting record time
                recordTime = 0;
                // Show TextView that displays record time
                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                    mRecorder.start();
                    // Change isRecroding flag to true
                    isRecording = true;
                    handler.post(UpdateRecordTime);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    FRLog.e("LOG_TAG", "prepare failed", e);
                }
```

When click audio playing:

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

private void playAudio(final SeekBar audioSeekbar, int position, final ImageButton audioplayImgBtn, String fileName) {
        seekBar = audioSeekbar;
        if (audio_playing && audio_position == position) {
            if (isPaused) {
                mPlayer.start();
                handler.post(UpdatePlayTime);
                audioplayImgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                isPaused = false;
            } else {
                mPlayer.pause();
                audioplayImgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_messages_audio_play);
                isPaused = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (audio_playing && audio_position != position) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                audioplayImgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_messages_audio_play);
                isPaused = true;
            }
            audio_position = position;
            audioSeekbar.setProgress(0);
            audioplayImgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer.release();
                    mPlayer = null;
                } else {
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer.release();
                    mPlayer = null;
                }
            }
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            playTime = 0;
            handler = new Handler();
            // Reset max and progress of the SeekBar
            try {
                // Initialize the player and start playing the audio
                mPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testing/" + fileName);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        audioSeekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
                        mPlayer.start();
                        audio_playing = true;
                        handler.post(UpdatePlayTime);
                    }
                });

                mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        audioplayImgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_messages_audio_play);
                        audioSeekbar.setProgress(0);
                        audio_playing = false;
                        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    }
                });
                // Post the play progress
                // updated code by manikandan
                audioSeekbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
                            mPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                audioSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean fromUser) {
                        if (mPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                            mPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        if (mPlayer != null) {
                            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                FRLog.e("LOG_TAG", "prepare failed", e);
            }
        }
    }




Runnable UpdatePlayTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```